# Default push button works just once

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a simple dialog box with a list box, edit box and two buttons, Send and Clear, Send being the default. When it is pressed the string is read from the edit box and added to the list box. Clear speaks for itself. When I press enter the first time everything works, however when I press enter a second time it doesn't respond/register. If the button is clicked everything works as intended.

I have tried to use DM_SETDEFID after changing the focus back to the edit box, this did nothing.

Stripped it of unnecessary code, so I hope nothing is missing.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK CHAT(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON1)
        {
                string strDisplay="You: "+strMessage;
                TCHAR szDisplay[MESSAGE_SIZE];
                strcpy_s(szDisplay, strDisplay.c_str());

                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)&szDisplay);
                SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, "");
            }
            SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1));
        }
        else if(LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON2)
        {
            SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, "");
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

In the resource file:

```
IDD_CHAT_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Chat"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Message:",IDC_STATIC,198,12,102,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,198,24,102,108,ES_MULTILINE
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Send",IDC_BUTTON1,198,138,104,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Clear",IDC_BUTTON2,198,156,104,14
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,7,7,185,167,LBS_NODATA | LBS_NOSEL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END
```

Comment: Are you able to post the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a multi-line edit control. As soon as it has the focus, then it will process all presses of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

That's by design. If the button handled presses of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key when the edit control has focus, how could you enter a new line in the edit control?

If you do need to stop the multi-line edit control from eating the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key then you can handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` to arrange that. The technique is explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/10/12/819674.aspx

---

As an aside, the strcpy_s is spurious. Call c_str() on your string and pass that directly to the API function.

Comment: Could I just use GetAsyncKeyState or should I redesign it instead of looking for a work around?

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` is no good. I added to the answer to explain the "right" way to do this. I do ask you though if you are sure you want to do this. How will the user enter line feeds in this edit control? Or is it read only?

Comment: The user will be sending (short) messages so newlines are not important, thanks for your help!